# Is there any Azure DevOps data retention period for OData Query?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I am building Power BI dashboard and I want to have a view of the trend of my organization data in Azure DevOps. My concern is there any data retention period for OData query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is there any data retention period for OData query?

AFAIK, there is no such data retention period for OData query.

That because the result of OData query query is real-time data of a database query, just like we use **Queries** to obtain real-time data. And those data will **not be cached on the azure devops service** like a pipelines.

So, there is no such data retention period for OData query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi @Leo, does it mean all historical data will forever be there?

Comment: @rick, As long as your workitem always exists, then you can query it at any time. The query data is real-time and does not need to be stored on the Azure devops UI/server, there will be no data retention period. Just like the database query statement, as long as the database exists, there is no limit to the data retention we query.

Answer (score 1):

As Leo has answered there is no documented retention period for the analytics data however it **is** retained.  The purpose of the data it to provide trend data over time so it would be highly unusual to delete it while the *project* was still active.

But also, to correct Leo, the data for a work item will still be in the analytics dataset even if you remove it from the project since it retains that historical view.

So you can build your dashboards safe in the knowledge that the data will always be there.